# String Compress in C# and Decompress in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am Compressing string using below code in C#.

```
 public static string Compress(string text)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

    byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
}
```

But Same String I want to Decompress in Javascript.

Can anyone help me to how decompress **String** in Javascript?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are talking about C# and JavaScript its in a HTTP context. For HTTP you would leave compression to the transport layer, which means the server does the compression as per HTTP negotiations of client and server capabilities. Compression is done either through static files or dynamics data, for example web services / web API. See [this page](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression) for instructions on setting up compression in IIS.

There are several reasons why you would not implement it yourself, ranging from code complexity, maintenance cost, time it takes to implement to the added risk of error.

If you have some special need for implementing compression between C# and JavaScript then the easiest would be to use industry standards. Your choice of gzip is good. A popular JavaScript library that support gzip is [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako).